# how does it work the custom lighting function in Unity StandardSurfaceshader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I made a custom lighting function that return float4(0,0,0,1) and expected the final color will be black, but it doesn't.
the gameObject is still colorful

the custom lighting function do nothing as if it doesn't work

why return value from custom lighting function doesn't affect on final color?

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
            float3 screenUV = IN.screenPos.xyz/ IN.screenPos.w;
            o.Emission = float3(screenUV.rg,0);
        }   

        float4 LightingSimple(SurfaceOutput s, float3 lightDir, float atten)
        {
            return float4(0,0,0,1);
        }
```